# Ubuntu 14.04 + iOS 8.0.2 unhandled lockdown error

Tags: iphone, ubuntu-14.04

I have Ubuntu 14.04 on my 4 laptops and IOS 8.0.2 on my 2 apple devices but cannot mount the Iphone Documents drive anymore since the 8.0.2 update on ANY laptop. I have spent 4 hours researching this issue and trying every amalgamation of:

'idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair'

and

'unplug + unlock + plugin your phone' sequence

all to no avail. When I try to mount it I get the 'unhandled lockdown error (-256)', then a trust this computer prompt, I confirm the trust message, then I get an 'unhandled lockdown error (-3)' error. I am convinced that this is a true bug that there is not straightforward solution to yet. I've noticed from searching around that older distros are not that affected but 14.04 users are getting it the most. Anyone get anymore ideas?

Comment: nope, still going on and I have since upgraded to 14.10 with the same result

Comment: ya i have the same issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was able to fix it with `libimobiledevice-utils` & `ifuse`

Disconnect your device and install packages.

```
sudo apt-get install libimobiledevice-utils ifuse
```

Restart your system.

Connect your device to your computer and run this command:

```
idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
```

If you phone shows "Trust computer" messages, select "Yes". By now it should connect.

If it is still throwing error, check if there is a directory `var/lib/lockdown`. If it is not there, create directory and change permissions for the directory.

```
sudo mkdir /var/lib/lockdown
sudo chmod 777 /var/lib/lockdown
```

Restart your system.

Connect your device and run

```
idevicepair unpair && idevicepair pair
```

Now You can access files from your device.

Sources:

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/02/fix-unhandled-lockdown-error-when.html
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2228772

Answer (score 4):

I solved the error -3 by plugin the iphone, selecting "trust computer", and then typing
`idevicepair pair`

Comment: Same result on all devices. Freezes and still cannot see the documents drive. I have tried your sequence multiple times already recently and in the past

Answer (score 1):

I searched for 2 hours and tried several solutions, none of them helped until finally I thought to try `sudo` with the `unpair` / `pair` commands and it worked instantly:

```
sudo idevicepair unpair && sudo idevicepair pair
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution is simple. Use following commands and next time you plug in your iPhone it would be explored properly.

1. Open terminal
2. fire command `sudo idevicepair pair`
3. get the <name> from message "SUCCESS: Paired with device <name>"
4. navigate to using `cd /var/lib/lockdown`
5. Confirm that ".plist" file exists by listing files using `ls` command
6. remove "<name>.plist" file using `sudo rm -f <name>.plist`
7. You are done

Let me know in either case for success or failure of solution.

Comment: Hi. At second step I got an error "Device <HASH> is not paired with this host". Still I can not access the phone

Comment: Upon 'sudo idevicepair pair' I get "ERROR: Device 00008027001E70423A22002E returned unhandled error code -5". Any idea how to fix?