# Ubuntu 14.04 + IOS 11.2.5 Unhandled Lockdown error (-3)

Tags: ios, ubuntu, virtualbox, lockdown, libimobiledevice

good morning,
i have an issue with my phone I want to plug in my phone so i can use it inside a virtualmachine (Mac os)but when I plug it while I'm still in my main system 
`Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty`
 I get this error
`Unhandled Lockdown error (-3)` I have tried to follow instructions mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26165939/ubuntu-14-04-ios-8-0-2-unhandled-lockdown-error) and in every other tutorial that I could find on the internet but nothing works
if there is a solution to this probleme or an alternative way to use my phone inside my virtualbox I would be thankful
PS: I'm using Oracle VM VirtualBox 5.1.18-114002
and I already added the extension pack

Comment: Did you look at https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/usb+virtualbox?

Comment: mainly my problem is getting my phone recognized by my computer (ubuntu as I mentioned in my post)

Answer (score 0):

The version of libimobiledevice that ships with Ubuntu 14.04 is outdated. The handshake protocol (the way the software running on your computer authenticates with the iPhone or iPad) has changed in the latest couple of version of libimobiledevice and  you need a new version of libimobiledevice.

Your best bet is to compile and install the following software from source:

- [libplist](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libplist)
- [libusbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libusbmuxd)
- [usbmuxd](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/usbmuxd)
- [libimobiledevice](https://github.com/libimobiledevice/libimobiledevice)

For each of the repositories, you'll need to `git clone` the repository, run `./autogen.sh`, `make` and then `sudo make install`

If you don't want to compile from source, and upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04 is an option, we maintain an Ubuntu PPA with up-to-date and precompiled versions of libimobiledevice at https://launchpad.net/~quamotion/+archive/ubuntu/ppa.

Comment: i did clone, autogen, make and make install as you said but still the same error.
is there some other configuration to do after that?

Comment: you'll probably want to check you are using the correct version of the libimobiledevice tools. Which utility are you using (e.g. `idevicesyslog`)? From which location?

Comment: i have upgraded my ubuntu to ubuntu 16.04 because i had to make it work as soon as possible so i can try to execute my app on the phone, but i don't know why once i did that i could plug in my phone easily without installing the libmobileidevice